# How do I find "$oid" in MongoDB instead of _id?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to do a find search in MongoDB and I just want to return the objectId as a string, but instead I get:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6114ffebae76283ccfb92c44"
    }
  }
[
```

I want:

```
[
  {
    "$oid": "6114ffebae76283ccfb92c44"
  }
]
```

Here is my query:

```
db.person.find(
    { $and: [{"age":20},{"name":"Frank"}] }, {"_id":1}
)
```

Comment: `$oid` should be the syntax of [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#mongodb-bsontype-ObjectId). You may be looking for [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) if you simply want to extract the "value" of ObjectId

Comment: Where (what tool, e.g., mongo shell, etc.) are you running the query from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could apply a `$toString` to get the id in your desired format.

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  "_id": {
    $toString: "$_id"
  }
})
```

However you can't use the `$oid` as field name because is a reserved keyword.

Example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/y1DsrQ-k4Hj

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: {
        $toString: "$_id"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can test it (I set the name of _id to id)

https://mongoplayground.net/p/xdw3PpiwYId

```js
db.person.find({
  $and: [
    {
      "age": 20
    },
    {
      "name": "Frank"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": {
    $toString: "$_id"
  },
  "_id": 0
})
```